# Access Token if stolen, can access resources from the service it is provided. how OAuth prevent it other than making it short interval expiration

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

I am new to OAuth2, was thinking about the scenario where Access Token if stolen, can access resources from the service it is provided. how OAuth2 prevent it other than making it short  interval expiration for access JWT Token.

Answer (score 0):

It can't really, if the token is a simple bearer token. As described in [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4), the client could be made to authenticate when using an access token:

> Additional authentication credentials, which are beyond
> the scope of this specification, may be required in order for the
> client to use a token

but that isn't usually done in practice.p

The token doesn't have to be a JWT - depending on the implementation, it's possible that a token revocation mechanism may also be in place which could be used if it was known that a token was stolen.

Tokens should be protected and only sent over HTTPS (a requirement of the spec).